# Кнопка нестандартной формы

Tags: javascript

Не совсем понимаю как сделать в javascript кнопку произвольной формы? Может кто сталкивался? Под произвольной формой я подразумеваю, к примеру, кнопку в виде буквы "М".

Comment: А что точнее нужно? Что значит произвольной формы? :)

Answer (score 2):

Просто нарисуйте её и используйте эту картинку как кнопку. Правда если вам надо обязательно сделать так, чтобы при клике в "дырку" нажатие не происходило, то придётся колупаться с проверкой координат клика.. а это уже довольно грустно.

Comment: В форме буквы «М» — не так уж грустно. Кроме того никто же не заставляет руками рисовать — взять любой готовый инструмент, мышкой нанести точечки по форме фигуры на картинку и скопипастить готовую карту.

Comment: Средствами CSS? Это как же так?

Comment: Да-да! Меня тоже научите! Я тоже хочу средствами CSS!

Comment: И я тоже!!! 10 лет прошли зря! Я не выучил как это делать на CSS!!!)))))))

Answer (score 1):

Еще вариант - сделать SVG-рисунок, который и будет кнопкой.

```
<html>
  <svg>
    <circle cx="25%" cy="25%" r="100" fill="url(#cool)" onmousedown="clickme();" />
  </svg>
</html>
```

Здесь используется кружок вместо буквы "М", но идея та же.

Comment: Охлол. Я уж не говорю про HTML5, но уж без JS точно можно было обойтись))).

Answer (score 0):

Возможно не совсем корректное решение, но можно наложить поверх кнопки нужную картинку с транспарентным фоном, а для самой кнопки выставить opacity=0 и filter:alpha(opacity=0).
Если нужно могу привести пример декорированного таким образом  "<"input type="file"/>"

Answer (score 0):

Короче говоря: таких кнопок в стандартах нет и я думаю, что не будет. Если хотите нестандартную область для клика - то проверяйте координаты (как сказал cy6ergn0m), если же хотите просто кучу тегов кнопкой, то используйте тег <button></button>. К чему вариант с прозрачностью был предложен я так и не понял, но он тоже нормальный, используется как раз только для <input type="file"/>. Вот и все :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="image" src="URL" />
```

Такой вариант не подходит?

Comment: Карта уже была предложена где-то в комментах :)